# "Run if I haven't been called in x seconds" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Suppose I have a callback firing perpetually as the result of some event; i.e. Someone's moving a mouse.

I'd like to run a cleanup action if the callback hasn't fired in x seconds; i.e. If they haven't moved the mouse in 2 seconds, fire.

I think I could probably fix something up with setTimeout, but I'm wondering if any standard libraries have a function for this? Sort of a 'dead-mans-switch', seems like it would be common enough to have a standard method. If not I'm making one. Anyone?

Comment: Look up the implementations for de-bouncing. Whilst it serves a different purpose the major implementations can be changed easily to provide you with your `::after` hook.

Comment: De-bounce is exactly what I'm looking for. Lodash and underscore have implementations, and other libraries probably do too. This is the correct answer-- if you are willing to copy this into an answer field, I would mark it as correct. You might include links to a couple common implementations  (i.e. Lodash) for fast reference by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De-bouncing may be a technique that will help.

It is essentially a method of wrapping a function so that you have control over when the wrapped function will execute, regardless of how often the debounced version is called.

This is most commonly used for events, like window resize. Then you can only execute your handler once the user has *finished* resizing the window rather then whilst they are resizing it.

There is also throttling, this is similar but has important differences.

Throttled functions will execute once every `n` time rather than a debounced version which will executed after it hasn't be called for `n` time.

[underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) and [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) have implementations of de-bouncing and throttling.

However they it is quite easy to achieve and you don't really need a large library if its not already being used.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ste2425! Very useful and concise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track about setTimeout. As per your wonder, I am not aware of a module that would do it. And due to the intrusive nature of this process, it makes sense.

You could do this tho:

```
var yourmodule; //assuming you're using a module to store your app code; the object should obviously exist before continuing
yourmodule.cleanupSequenceId = -1;

function yourEventCallback() {
    if (yourmodule.cleanupSequenceId !== -1) clearTimeout(yourmodule.cleanupSequenceId);

    //function logic

    //cleanup:
    yourmodule.cleanupSequenceId = setTimeout(cleanupMethod, 2000);
}
```

Comment: It's safe to clear a timeout that doesn't exist, so there's no need to check that it's not -1 before clearing it.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout - "Passing an invalid ID to clearTimeout() silently does nothing; no exception is thrown."

Answer (score 0):

After stumbling upon this (very old) question, and reading many others like it, I found a solution that works for me so I wanted to share it.

You define a "Debounce" function like this:

```
var debounce_timeout // Global debouncer timer, so all calls target this specific timeout.
function debounce(func, delay = 2000) {
    clearTimeout(debounce_timeout)
    debounce_timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        func()
    }, delay)
}
```

Now if you wish to debounce some function, you do:

```
debounce(myFunction)
```

Debouncing essentially means, that when your function is called, we observe for 'delay' duration, if any other calls to the function is made. If another call is made, we reset our observing time.